# How to convert text to time with negative durations?

Tags: r, time

I would like to convert `c("2:25", "-3:45")` to a time vector of format `"h:m"` and and get the mean of the vector `mean(c("2:25", "-2:25"))` that would return `"0:0"`. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

With `lubridate` you can easily create objects of `Duration` class:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- c("2:25", "-3:45")
l <- lapply(strsplit(x, ":"), as.numeric)
lst <- lapply(l, function(x) {if(x[1] < 0) x[2] <- x[2]-2*x[2];x})
res <- lapply(lst, function(x) duration(as.numeric(x[1]), "hours")+
         duration(as.numeric(x[2]), "minutes"))
#[[1]]
#[1] "8700s (~2.42 hours)"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "-13500s (~-3.75 hours)"
duration(mean(unlist(res)), "seconds")
#[1] "-2400s (~-40 minutes)"
```

The second example:

```
x2 <- c("2:25", "-2:25")
l <- lapply(strsplit(x2, ":"), as.numeric)
lst <- lapply(l, function(x) {if(x[1] < 0) x[2] <- x[2]-2*x[2];x})
res <- lapply(lst, function(x) duration(as.numeric(x[1]), "hours")+
         duration(as.numeric(x[2]), "minutes"))
#[[1]]
#[1] "8700s (~2.42 hours)"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "-8700s (~-2.42 hours)"
duration(mean(unlist(res)), "seconds")
#[1] "0s"
```

Answer (score 0):

"duration" from "lubridate" is not really necessary. "difftime" from "base" is good enough:

```
x <- c("2:25", "-3:45", "1:11", "-0:03")
A <- abs(matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x,":"))),nrow=2))
A[,grep("-",x)] <- -A[,m]

t <- as.difftime(t(A) %*% c(60,1), unit="mins")
```

Result:

```
> t
Time differences in mins
     [,1]
[1,]  145
[2,] -225
[3,]   71
[4,]   -3
> mean(t)
Time difference of -3 mins
```

The first row of the matrix "A" contains the hours, the second row the minutes. One has to neglect the "-"-signs temporarily, because they are valid for hours *and*
minutes. Subsequently the columns corresponding to negative times are completely multiplied by -1.

If the desired output format is "HH:MM" one can use "sprintf":

```
mt <- mean(t)

c <- sprintf( "%s%02i:%02.0f",
              ifelse(as.numeric(mt)<0,"-","+"),
              abs(as.numeric(mt)) %/% 60,
              abs(as.numeric(mt)) %% 60 )
```

Result:

```
> c
[1] "-00:03"
```